# How to use document.createElement with elapsedTime?

Tags: javascript, html, css

I'm making a game for a school project. The premise is that there will be enemies coming from the right side of the screen, and you will have to kill them. I've managed to create them so they are shown, but i can't manage to make them not come in at the same time.
Any tips on how i should go on with this?

(Sorry if this is badly formulated, i am very new to these things)

I've tried different ways of achieviving my goal trough using the elapsedTime function but i can't seem to make it work in the slightest.

```
function createEnemy() {
  for(var i = 0; i < antallFiender; i++) {
    var nyFiende = document.createElement("img");
    nyFiende.setAttribute("src", "tenor.gif");
    nyFiende.setAttribute("class", "zombie");
    nyFiende.style.top = Math.floor(Math.random()*800) + "px";

    barnetEl.appendChild(nyFiende);
  }
  var zombieEl = document.querySelectorAll(".zombie");
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use JavaScript `setInterval` function. With this function you can pass a callback in the first parameter, and a time interval (in miliseconds) as the second parameter, that is the time between the calls of your callback. So it will be something like this:

```
function createEnemy() {
  var nyFiende = document.createElement("img");
  nyFiende.setAttribute("src", "tenor.gif");
  nyFiende.setAttribute("class", "zombie");
  nyFiende.style.top = Math.floor(Math.random()*800) + "px";

  barnetEl.appendChild(nyFiende);
  var zombieEl = document.querySelectorAll(".zombie");
}

setInterval(createEnemy, 1000);
```

This way, every 1 second your function will be called to create one enemy.

If you want to stop the function from being called, you should assign the interval to a variable, so you can use `clearInterval` to stop it, like this:

```
var enemyInterval = setInterval(createEnemy, 1000);

clearInterval(enemyInterval);
```

Hope it helps you.